# Identify this chord: F# (bass) + C + E + A

Tags: chords, terminology

Would someone be able to identify this chord for me?

- A
- E
- C
- F# - bass

I'm sure it's obvious but I can't seem to figure it out.

It's a song in the key of C major.  A C major chord precedes it and an F major chord follows it

Comment: there are a couple of ways this chord could be named; knowing the chord(s) that precedes and (especially) follows it would be useful in understanding the harmonic context.

Comment: Added the context of the chord to the main article

Comment: it would be great to have greater context (more chords before and after) and to know the name of the song or piece. As you can see by the answers, this is not so clear cut.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It really depends on context. It could be an Am6, but this is an unlikely inversion, so probably not. It could be an F#m7b5, especially if followed by some form of B7, where it would serve as a II in E, probably E minor. For other functions of half-diminished chords, see [Wikipedia: Half-diminished Seventh Chord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-diminished_seventh_chord). It could also be a rootless D9 voicing with the third in the root, especially if followed by some sort of G.

If you can give us more context, we can better figure out how the chord is *functioning* and give you a more accurate answer.

**Edit for updated question**: This is F#m7b5 serving in a diminished function as a chromatic passing chord preceding the F. It could also be serving in a secondary dominant function, as a [tritone substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritone_substitution) for the V of IV, if it can be considered an F#7b5#9 in a voicing without the third (think C/F# to better visualize its dominant function). It is described in more detail in the previously mentioned wikipedia article as a [Sharpened subdominant with minor seventh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-diminished_seventh_chord#Sharpened_subdominant_with_minor_seventh), and appears in the Super Mario Bros. theme and The Entertainer (but not followed by the IV), although that section doesn't specifically address its function when preceding the IV.

In any event, I am now curious as to what song this is.

Comment: I was going to mention The Entertainer but it's followed by the V in that context. The I #ivø7 IV is a little different.

Comment: @James Yeppers.

Comment: @James also, Night and Day contains a #ivø7 iv.

Comment: I've actually heard it in a couple of places recently. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqNajM6RDws#t=0m55) (under the lyrics "There's nothing I can do") and also [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-yUO15brzU&feature=related#t=1m16) (under the lyric "try your very best to *hide*")

Enjoy!

Comment: @James I'm not able to hear the chord in the entertainer - whereabouts is it?

Comment: @David bar 11; the melody is literally F# A C E; it's arguably a D9, though

Comment: @David @James it's literally the notes of F#ø but functionally it's a rootless D9 arpeggio, the V of V. It lacks the chromatic bass movement necessary to really distinguish it as a F#ø. The interesting thing about advanced jazz harmony is that many chords with the same function become more-or-less equivalent. Is it a F#ø or a rootless D9 when followed by a GM7? Whichever. At that point it's more about color, bass movement and voice leading than complex chord names. At least, when I play I tend to think in those terms, and not about the chord notation.

Comment: @James ah, got it. I had to stumble through it on the guitar to figure it out, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @Rein yes, in a way this question and its answers and discussion have been a great demonstration of the inadequacies of traditional chord labeling

Answer (score 7):

It's an F#m7-5 (F# minor 7, flat 5), aka an F# half-diminished chord.  It's the diatonic seventh chord built on the seventh degree of the G-major scale.  In root position, it would be voiced F#-A-C-E.

It could also be a D7/9, without the D.  In root position, it would be D-F#-A-C-E

Answer (score 3):

It's just an A minor sixth (Am6).  In root position, it would be A-C-E-F<sup>#</sup>.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for adding the context. Makes it much clearer it's a **half-diminished seventh chord** or, even more specifically in this context, a **sharpened subdominant diminished triad with minor seventh**.